# What is the right number of clusters for gene expression data using different methods?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I have a normalized gene expression data for which I want to find the optimal number of clusters. Using `mclust` package after preparing the data,

I am using the following to rank the data.

```
ranked.exprs <- probe_ranking(input=exp_file,
    probe_number=2000, 
    probe_num_selection="Fixed_Probe_Num",
    data.exp=genes, 
    method="SD_Rank")
```

Using

```
#Calculate number of clusters 
cluster_num <- number_clusters(data.exp=genes, Fixed=NULL,
    gap_statistic=TRUE)
# I get 8 

#checking silhouette values for kmeans
resukm <-fviz_nbclust(ranked.exprs, FUNcluster = kmeans, method = c("silhouette"), diss = NULL, k.max = 10, nboot = 10,
  verbose = interactive(), barfill = "steelblue", barcolor = "steelblue",
  linecolor = "steelblue", print.summary = TRUE)
#results to 2 clusters

#running the gap statistic using hierarchical clustering 
gap_stat <- clusGap(genes, FUN=hcut, K.max = 10, B = 50)
#results to 2 clusters

#checking silhouette values for hierarchical clustering 
resuhie <-fviz_nbclust(genes, FUNcluster = hcut, method = c("silhouette"), diss = NULL, k.max = 10, nboot = 10,
  verbose = interactive(), barfill = "steelblue", barcolor = "steelblue",
  linecolor = "steelblue", print.summary = TRUE)
#results to 2 clusters
```

What could be reason for getting two different numbers 8 and 2? My data contains missing values as well.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is *no* reason to assume that the optimum numbers for method A and B are the same.

Secondly, the measures are just heuristics, so they may give different values.

Hence I wouldn't have been surprised if you got 4 different values!

And yet, likely none of these results is good. Because the methods and the measures are designed for different data, not for gene expression data.

Comment: How can I know which method is suitable for my dataset? I tried to use ``Nbclust()`` function to calculate the cluster numbers with different methods and to use the majority rule to decide which number is the right one, but it didn't work for my data, I got the error that the TSS matrix is indefinite or there are so many missing values. I need to use all the genes in my dataset so I don't want to subset my data. What would you suggest? Is there any way to find the right method or make the Nbclust to work in case we want to use majority rule?

Comment: You have to choose methods based on their theory, whether that matches your requirements and the data properties. With genes, you'll likely find biclustering more appropriate.